# LDAP group membership (including Domain Users)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, member, adsi, ldap-query

How can I get a list of users within an LDAP group, even if that group happens to be the primary group for some users?

For example, suppose "Domain Users" is "Domain Leute" in German.  I want all members of "CN=Domain Leute,DC=mycompany,DC=com".  How would I know that is the well-known "Domain Users" group?

Or what if some users' primary group was changed to "CN=rebels,DC=mycompany,DC=com", and I wanted to get members of THAT group?  Users don't have a memberOf property for their primary group, and the primary group won't have a member property listing them.

This is what I see when viewed via LDAP (ie, no MS extensions):
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find out primaryGroupToken from the Group object first.  If you are using ADSIEdit, you need to make sure you have "Constructed" filter on to see this calculated attribute.  For Domain Users, the primaryGroupToken should be 513.

Then, you neeed to find all the users with primaryGroupID set to this value.  Here is the ldap query you should write to find out all users with Domain Users set as the primary group.

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=513))
```

**EDIT**

Here is the steps to show primaryGroupToken in LDAP Browser.  I am using LDAP browser 2.6 build 650.  Right click your profile and click properties

[image]

Go to LDAP Settings tab and click Advanced button.

[image]

Add an extra operational attribute *primaryGroupToken*

Click **Apply** button and close the properties page.  Now, you should see the *primaryGroupToken* in your group object.

[image]

Comment: And that's basically my question -- how do you find out the primaryGroupToken from any given group?  (Hopefully using LDAP calls)

Comment: Please let me know what tools you are using.  I could get it using ldp.exe, adsiedit.msc or even C# code.  I don't know what problem you are seeing when trying to retrieve primaryGroupToken

Comment: I'm looking at CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mydomain.  I'm using Softerra's LDAP Browser (free -- very nice too), so pure LDAP without any MS extensions.  No attributes that equal 513 or could even be twisted into a 513 :)

Comment: @DougN: I just downloaded the LDAP Browser and it also works but it needs some more configuration. You need to right click on your profile and see the properties. Inside the properties page, go to LDAP settings tab. Click the Advanced button. Go to Displayed Attributes tab. Make sure Display operation attributes is selected. Then, you can check "Display extra operational attributes from the list below. Click New buton and add "primaryTokenGroup" there.

Comment: @DougN What's wrong with my answer?  Why can't you accept it?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't gone back and verified with code yet.  Will accept now.

Answer (score 7):

To get the the primaryGroupToken from any given group extract it from the objectSid so for example **Domain Users** objectSid = `S-1-5-21-704657944-2065781323-617630493-513` then the **primaryGroupToken** is the last digits after the "-" so in the case of the "Domain Users" its `513`

Answer (score 0):

This is a PS script that I made to do exactly that:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices");

$groupName = "Grupo Domain";

$directoryEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry;
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry, "(&(objectClass=group)(CN=$groupName))");
[void]$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
[void]$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
$result = $directorySearcher.FindOne();

if ($result -eq $null) { return; }

# Try get the group members through the "member" property.
if ($result.Properties["member"].Count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($member in $result.Properties["member"]) {
        $memberSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry, "(&(objectClass=*)(distinguishedName=$member))");
        [void]$memberSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-PrincipalName");
        $memberResult = $memberSearcher.FindOne();
        if ($memberResult -eq $null) { continue; }
        Write-Output $memberResult.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"];
    }
    return;
}
if ($result.Properties["objectSid"].Count -gt 0) {
    # The group might be an AD primary group. Try get the members by the PrimaryGroupID.
    $groupSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($result.Properties["objectSid"][0], 0);
    # Hacky way to get only the last RID.
    $primaryGroupSid = $groupSid.Value.Replace($groupSid.AccountDomainSid.ToString(), [String]::Empty).TrimStart('-');
    $memberSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry, "(&(objectClass=*)(primaryGroupId=$primaryGroupSid))");
    [void]$memberSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-PrincipalName");
    $memberResult = $memberSearcher.FindAll();
    if ($memberResult -eq $null) { continue; }
    foreach ($member in $memberResult) {
        Write-Output $member.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"];
    }
}
```