# PHP ActiveDirectory through LDAP - How to find the name of a users primary group?

Tags: php, ldap

So I want to retrieve the group name of a users primary group.

I already know how to retrieve the primaryGroupID but I haven't found a field in the group class, that holds such an id.

Thats how I retrieve the primaryGroupID:

```
$filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $username . ")";
$attr = array ( "primaryGroupID", "sAMAccountName" );
$result = ldap_search( $ldap, "DC=ad,DC=test,DC=local", $filter, $attr ) or exit( "Unable to search LDAP server" . ldap_error( $ldap ) );
$entries = ldap_get_entries( $ldap, $result );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but this is definitely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443824/ldap-group-membership-including-domain-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primaryGroupID is actually the [RID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305475) of the group you need to get. Basically what you need to do to determine the actual group is the following:

1. Obtain the `objectSid` and `primaryGroupID` attributes from the user.
2. Convert the `objectSid` of the user to its string form.
3. Replace the last set of digits in the string SID with the `primaryGroupID`
4. Search for a group with an `objectSid` equal to the SID from the last step.

This is a pretty tedious task for something that pretty much never changes. But here's how I currently decode the `objectSid` from LDAP:

https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools/blob/master/src/LdapTools/AttributeConverter/ConvertWindowsSid.php

Just pass the value to the `fromLdap($value)` function. Then with the string version of the SID get the SID of the group like so:

```
$groupSid = preg_replace('/\d+$/', $primaryGroupId, $userSid);
```

Now using the above `$groupSid` you can search for a group with an `objectSid` equal to that.